# What kind of data that I need to do my PCA?

Tags: pca, data-transformation, biplot

So I have a not normal data (I did saphiro test and the result said it's not normal)

Then, I did data transform with log. So the data went normal.

Does the log data can work for my pca?

Or should I use my non normal data?

Answer (score 4):

PCA does not require normally distributed data. You should take logs if they make substantive sense (this often happens with variables that relate to money). However, extreme outliers and such can affect PCA, but that might not be bad.